# When should I use "" to quote a value in shell test and in echo?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm writing bash script like this:

```
VF_ETH=$(command)
if [ -n "$VF_ETH" ] ; then
    echo "ixgbevf eth: "$VF_ETH
fi
```

command is a linux command, my question is:

1. `$VF_ETH` is to get value of `VF_ETH`, why use `""` to quote it in `line2` in shell test?
2. if I do not use `""` to quote it, will test failed?
3. if use `""` to quote a value is to make it into string, why not use in echo in `line3`?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you get an actual command stored in `VF_ETH` variable, which contains spaces. Now if you use `if [ -n $VF_ETH ]` and when shell expands the variable, there will be multiple parameters to `-n` whereas it expects only one. Hence you might get something like `binary operator expected` error.

Also in the echo command, it is not mandatory to have only one parameter. Hence even if you are not using double quotes, it works.

Hence to avoid it, always use double quotes while expanding variables.

Also use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check your script and it will give you correct information on where your script is wrong/not as per standard.

Comment: Thank you, did you mean that the return value(which is $VF_ETH) of command may be several tokens include space, such as "A B C". Then we if we use $VF_ETH, it will be "A"?

Comment: No. `$VF_ETH` will be `A B C` but if any command expects only 1 argument and if you pass `A B C` without double quotes, they would be treated as 3 arguments.

Comment: To make my point, try creating a directory named `A B C`. First try `mkdir A B C` and then try `mkdir "A B C"` . You will understand the difference.

Answer (score 2):

You should always double quote variables used in command line arguments and within `[ ... ]` tests, for example:

```
ls "$var"
echo "$var"
[ -f "$var" ]
test -f "$var"
```

In all the above examples the commands used will receive different values with and without the double quotes, when the value of `$var` starts with a bunch of spaces *and* contains some spaces. For example:

```
var=" an apple"
echo "$var"  # prints " an apple"
echo $var    # prints "an apple", without the leading space
```

You don't need to quote them in *simple assignments*, for example:

```
a=$var
a=$var$b
```

If the assignment contains spaces or other special characters, then you have to quote, or escape those special characters:

```
a="$var $b"
a=$var\ $b
a=$var" "$b
```

All the above are equivalent, but the first one is probably the easiest to read, and therefore recommended.

You don't need to quote special variables that never have unsafe values, for example:

```
test $? = 0
```

If you're unsure, or not yet confident, then a good role of thumb is to double quote always.

Answer (score 0):

For 1. and 2. If you set `$VF_ETH="x -a -z x"` and test it with code:

```
if [ -n $VF_ETH ] ; then
  echo yes 
else 
  echo nope
fi
```

the output will be `nope` as the the inside of the square brackets would expand to `-n x AND -z x` (nonempty and empty). Adding quotes around the variable would fix that.

3. Set `$VF_ETH="*"`. Now if you `echo $foo` bash would do wildcard expansion and `echo` would output the contents of your current directory.